# checking boolean property in XML(Spring)

Tags: java, xml, spring

I am using Spring Framework .
While writing custom queries, I am unable check a parameter of boolean value.
For example this is not working:

```
<isEqual property="booleanVariable" compareValue="0">
do some SQl codes
</isEqual>
```

The above checking is not working, it is evaluating as equal in both the cases when `booleanVariable` is true and false .

I tried to replace `compareValue="true"` and "false".

Is it possible to check the boolean property in XML like above?

Comment: Are you sure you tried '<isEqual property="booleanVariable" compareValue="true">'  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<isEqual property="booleanVariable" compareValue="true/false">` to compare boolean values.

In java a boolean has no relationship to 1 or 0. The primitive type is always true or false